# Is there a way to use one form for all templates?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I've been trying to create this search function in my navigation bar that would be available in all pages of my site, using flask.

I need to add it to my layout template which extends to all my other templates. Is there an easier way to do this without having to go through each route and adding this form to it? Right now it just gives me an error since all my other routes don't recognize the form.

It seems really tedious if I had to add this specific search form to all of my routes.

My navbar search function looks something like this:

```
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('main.searchresults', search=searchq) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="md-form active-cyan active-cyan-2">
                  <a class="md-form active-cyan active-cyan-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">{{ searchbar.search }}</a>

              </div>
        </form>
                  <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('main.searchresults', search=searchq) }}">{{ searchbar.submit(class="btn btn-outline-primary") }}</a>
```

I could solve this by adding this Flaskform (defined as searchbar) that im using to all of my routes but Im hoping (and assuming) that theres an easier way to do this since it seems really inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jinja for your templates, you can create a file (for example `includes/_navbar.html`) for your navigation bar and include it in your templates.

```
{% include 'includes/_navbar.html' %}
```

You usually have some sort of "base" HTML file that all other files inherit/includes from. An example would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% include 'includes/_navbar.html' %}

        <div class="container">
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>


        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, for all your templates, you extend this base template. For example

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <img src="../static/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="160" height="120">
        {% if session.get('logged_in') %}
            <h1>Welcome {{ session.user.username }}!</h1>
        {% else %}
            <h1>Welcome to My website!</h1>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: So the contents of includes/_navbar.html would be the navbar by itself? I do have a base html page but ill try to separate the navbar from it and use include

Comment: @il5amees Yes, it should be by itself. I have a example program [here](https://github.com/Naxaes/Tweeter) and [here](https://github.com/Naxaes/Tweeter/blob/master/app/templates/includes/_navbar.html) is the navbar in that project. [Here](https://github.com/Naxaes/Tweeter/tree/master/app/templates) are all templates.

Comment: Your examples do make sense, however Im using {{ form. }} inside the navbar, so when you export or use include it gives an error jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'searchbar' is undefined. Sorry, I should've made it more clear what I was trying to do. Will edit my post in a bit.

Comment: @il5amees Oh right, I think I read your question a bit too hastily. So your problem is that you don't want to go to all your routes (in the python file) and add the parameter `form`? You have to do so unfortunately, but it's possible to wrap that in a function.

Comment: I see, well thanks anyways. Learned about the 'include' function from this. Hopefully there is a way to do this that someone can point out later.